# Data Returned When Both Table Have Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a simple query where I've to show data from two tables. The condition is if the alloment table has data and the leave details has no data, then it should show data from the allotment table only. In my case, when both the tables have data, it shows up the data. Tried with this but returns when both the tables have data:

```
SELECT K.EMPNO, K.LV_NAME, K.ALLOTMENT, K.REMAIN, M.LV_FROM, M.LV_TO
FROM  LV_ADJ_DETAILS m
LEFT JOIN TBL_LV_ALLOTMENT k 
    ON M.EMPNO = K.EMPNO
WHERE K.EMPNO = 'EMP00259'
  AND K.YEAR_NAME = '2018'
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.LV_TO) = '2018';
```

Expected Output: For the year **2018**

If both table have data -

```
EMPNO       LV_NAME             ALLOTMENT REMAIN   LV_FROM        LV_TO
EMP00259    MLWP                    0      0      4/22/2018     4/30/2018           
EMP00259    Maternity Leave        103    103     5/20/2018     5/22/2018
EMP00259    MLWP                    0      0      5/24/2018     5/26/2018
EMP00259    Maternity Leave        103    103     5/28/2018     5/30/2018
```

If one table has data - If no leave details like leave from and to

```
EMPNO           LV_NAME             ALLOTMENT REMAIN LV_FROM        LV_TO
EMP00259        MLWP                    0       0           
EMP00259        Maternity Leave 103    103     103
```

**Script**:

```
CREATE TABLE HRD.TBL_LV_ALLOTMENT
(
  EMPNO      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  LV_NAME    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  YEAR_NAME  INTEGER,
  ALLOTMENT  NUMBER,
  ENJOY      NUMBER,
  REMAIN     NUMBER,
  STATUS     INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE HRD.LV_ADJ_DETAILS
(
  EMPNO       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  APP_NO      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  LEAVE_NAME  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  APV_DAYS    NUMBER(3),
  LV_FROM     DATE,
  LV_TO       DATE,
  BALANCE     NUMBER(3),
  COM_ID      VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
)
```

**Note**: I am filtering with year in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing with outer joins is to get the table order correct. With a LEFT OUTER JOIN the table with all the table comes before the join and the table with some of the table comes after. You say ...

> if the alloment table has data and the leave details has no data, then it should show data from the allotment table only

... so the correct join order is `tbl_lv_allotment k left outer join lv_adj_details m`.

There is also a gotcha when filtering in outer joins, and you have fallen prey to it. By including `m.lv_to` in the WHERE clause criteria you will discard any rows where `m.lv_to` is null, which short-circuits the outer join. There are a couple of ways of fixing this, but the simplest is to test for null:

```
select k.empno
        , k.lv_name 
        , k.allotment
        , k.remain
        , m.lv_from
        , m.lv_to
from  tbl_lv_allotment k 
      left outer join lv_adj_details m
           on m.empno = k.empno
where k.empno = 'EMP00259'
and k.year_name = '2018'
and ( m.lv_to is null or extract(year from m.lv_to) = '2018' );
```

However, depending on your data it may be better to use a subquery:

```
select k.empno
        , k.lv_name 
        , k.allotment
        , k.remain
        , m.lv_from
        , m.lv_to
from  tbl_lv_allotment k 
    left outer join ( select * from lv_adj_details
                       where extract(year from lv_to) = '2018' ) m
    on m.empno = k.empno
where k.empno = 'EMP00259'
  and k.year_name = '2018'
  ;
```

Here is [a demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c7e5/5) using a version of your query, showing how the WHERE clause subverts the outer join.

---

In the Fiddle I altered the join criteria to include `and m.leave_name = k.lv_name`. This removes the horrible product you get from matching all the rows in one table to all the the rows in the other. I haven't done that here, because I think code in the answer should produce the output shown in the question.

Comment: It almost worked @APC but I posted wrong. The query should retrieve only the data of the specific year. Could you check the output again?

Comment: I corrected the year when I did the SQL Fiddle. It works there, it should work for you

Comment: Worked perfect now @APC and modified a bit. This section **left outer join ( select * from lv_adj_details where extract(year from lv_to) = '2018' ) m** into **ON M.EMPNO = K.EMPNO AND M.LEAVE_NAME = K.LV_NAME AND K.YEAR_NAME = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.LV_TO)** - Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You want to select from table `tbl_lv_allotment` and outer join records from table `lv_adj_details`, but you have it vice versa.

Then imagine the situation that the main table has no match in the outer joined table. Then you get a row with all columns of the outer joined table being null. If you then have a condition in your `WHERE` clause on that table (such as `K.EMPNO = 'EMP00259'` in your query) then you dismiss the row right away, because in an outer joined row this value is null. This renders your outer join a mere inner join. Criteria on outer joined tables belongs in the `ON` clause:

```
select a.empno, a.lv_name, a.allotment, a.remain, d.lv_from, d.lv_to
from tbl_lv_allotment a
left join lv_adj_details d on  d.empno = a.empno
                           and to_char(d.lv_to, 'yyyy') = a.year_name
where a.empno = 'EMP00259'
  and a.year_name = '2018';
```

I've changed `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.LV_TO) = '2018'` (which should be `2018`, not `'2018'` because you are dealing with a number here) to `to_char(d.lv_to, 'yyyy') = a.year_name`, because obviously this is about matching the year of the main table.

Answer (score 1):

This condition `(AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.LV_TO) = '2018')` in where clause makes the issue.

Try this:

```
SELECT K.EMPNO, K.LV_NAME, K.ALLOTMENT, K.REMAIN, M.LV_FROM, M.LV_TO 
FROM  LV_ADJ_DETAILS m 
LEFT JOIN TBL_LV_ALLOTMENT k 
    ON M.EMPNO = K.EMPNO AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM M.LV_TO) = '2018'
WHERE K.EMPNO = 'EMP00259' AND K.YEAR_NAME = '2018';
```

Comment: Thanks for it @DineshDB but didn't work. Any alternate?